# Django. Saving session data for unauthenticated (anonymous) user

Tags: django, session

Django isn't saving session data from an anonymous (unauthenticated) user. Should this not work?

1. Unauthenticated user goes to URL. Server-side a session variable is set.
2. User clicks on link and another page loads. Server-side it checks for existence of session variable.
3. I expect the previous session variable to be available, but it's not. If the user is authenticated then it works OK.

   ```
   if is_starting_url():
       # user does get here the first time.
       request.session["my_param"] = "1"
   elif "my_param" in request.session:
       # user not getting here
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's because I had a

```
logout(request)
```

in the call.